# Writing pdf content to java.io.Writer

Tags: java, pdf, char, arrays

We have a pdf file with text and images which we need to write on `java.io.Writer` as a requirement.

We were able to read the pdf in a `byte[]` but the `java.io.Writer` requires a `char[]` to be passed. This is resulting in file getting corrupted and we are not able to open the pdf file.

Please suggest any workarounds though which this can be achieved.

Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: show your code and provide data samples

Comment: Writing binary data (like a PDF file) into a character stream is very likely to cause corruption. It would be better to find a way to use a java.io.OutputStream instead. Do you at least have control over the character encoding that the writer will eventually use to convert chars to bytes?

Answer (score -1):

How about using `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Pass it your byte array in `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` then output it to a file with `writeTo(OutputStream out)` where `out` is a `FileOutputStream`.